# Storing document now for multiple pages in external files

Tags: javascript, jquery

Each of my 10-15 pages has 100-200 lines of js inside `$(document).ready()`

Would it be wise to combine them all into one external file? I don't understand how that would work. Wouldn't the browser have to check for everything all at once, even the functions that are not on the current page? The second issue would probably be function conflicts.

Please give me some tips on how to handle this.

Comment: I would only combine them if it would result in less overall code, for example, reusable code vs copying the same code into multiple files.

Comment: @KevinB the code is different for each page, but I could benefit from making it cacheable.

Comment: you could also look into things such as making all of your form handlers use the same code, lazy-binding ui widgets such as datepickers and autocomplete fields, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split those lines to several files if your js file becomes too big.
Just note that 100-200 lines is very small. You should minify your code if the size is  really important for you.

*"We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature 
optimization is the root of all evil"*

Regarding to functions conflicts, use namespaces, and closures and keep your global object clean as possible.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the size of external files. Rather about improving the page load speed of each page (they are used very frequently). But I'm not sure if putting it all in one file would actually speed something up, because there would be so much stuff in the global reach.

Comment: @domino. It will speed up things. this file will be downloaded once, and for all other pages, it will be cached.

Comment: Would you suggest putting the code for each page in a separate function in the combined file, and then making the calls when needed?

Comment: @domino. If the code in one page can't be reused for other pages, yes. I would use a "global" js file with infrastructural functions, and add a js file for each function with it's specific functions.

Answer (score 1):

would it be wise? yes.
you give the browser one big cachable chunk that he doesnt have to worry about anymore what improves page loading speed.
put all your onload events in differently named functions and call them from the relevant pages, or reuse functions on different pages if they have to do the same.

Comment: I like the functions idea, hadn't thought about that. Easier to keep it clean.

Answer (score 1):

There are various things you must look into.

First remove all the js to public cdn where possible for ex jquery
Secondly always minify & combine all js to one file ( same applies for css too)

The advantage here is if you have 10 js file browser has to make ten requests and receive each file separately. Not to mention about the number of requests per domain in mobile devices.

On the other end if all the files are are sent as one file there is only one request . You are right that it will take a lot of time executing (or at least checking all the onready stuffs) but this processing time is much much much lower than the request time that would occur if files are different.

Comment: I use headjs which loads everything parallel.